# require('google-closure-library') in create-react-app causes Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'module' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, google-closure-library

This can be reproduced by 3 simple steps.

1. Create a new [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/): `npx create-react-app myApp`
2. Install [Google Closure Library](https://github.com/google/closure-library): `npm install google-closure-library`
3. Import closure library into App.js: `require('google-closure-library');`

Now running the react app with `npm start` we get an exception in the browser console. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'module' has already been declared`.

Trying to use `goog.require(...)` or anything similar results in a compiler error stating: `Failed to compile. 'goog' is not defined`. This is probably a side effect of the first error.

There seems to be a `module` variable in the google closure library that does not play well with another `module` variable already existing in the react app.

Is google-closure-library simply incompatible with create-react-app or what is going on here?